# apache mod_proxy_ajp tomcat incomplete files occasionally

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, apache-2.4

We have an issue where some users are seeing incomplete files returned from the web server that are proxied to Tomcat using mod_proxy_ajp

apache 2.4.6 
tomcat version 7.0.27

The files in question are over 40MB, some users are seeing it complete at 10MB or so, all the way up to the full file size.

The tomcat access logs report the file was fully sent when looking at bytes transmitted, the web server indicates the size received by the end user. Most of the time the web server response code is 200, rarely it's 206.

I'm a little stumped as to what to look at next to even try and determine where this problem may be happening.